# How to get ability to start up multiple same Adobe Air applications?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, air

How to be able to start up same Adobe Air applications multiple times? How to make it to my app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multiple instances are not supported, but you can work around it.

If you want the feature to support being run multiple times, you can respond to the [InvokeEvent.INVOKE](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/jslr/flash/events/InvokeEvent.html) event dispatched by the [NativeApplication](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/jslr/flash/desktop/NativeApplication.html). You can then open a new window and make it appear that the application is running multiple times.

Alternatively, if you are simply trying to run the application multiple times to test a connection to a server without using multiple machines, you can change the value of the `<id>` element in your application descriptor.

Comment: SO YOU SAY EACH TIME USER runs an air app (starts up an app like doble click on an icon) if that app already is started up it gets that event?!? 
Wow... Cool!) Thanks... going to test it out as soon as possible=)